# How to keep the data in file.txt?

Tags: c, function, file, fgets

I want to store the data in file.txt even if I run the code again. Whenever I run the code it removes all the previous data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char sentence[1000];  
    FILE *fptr = fopen("file.txt", "w");

    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", sentence);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't want the previous data to be removed. So what do you want? To append new data to the existing contents?

Comment: I don't want to replace that old data whenever I enter the new one. I want to store everytime I enter data.

Comment: You just need to change the mode write to append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file in "append" mode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char sentence[1000];  
    FILE *fptr = fopen("file.txt", "a"); /*  <===== changed from "w" to "a" */

    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", sentence);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

New data will now be added at the end of the file.